# Is it possible to export data from Facebook's graph search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-search

I'm trying to find a way of getting the location of friends of friends (town/city and country) and plot them on a map.

I can easily search for "Friends of my friends" but is there a way of exporting the results to CSV, json, or some other easily parsed format?

Answer (score -2):

I do not use Facebook every day, so I don't know,  but if exist any Graph Search API, it can be possible to export data.

Comment: That's what I was asking.